# MaxHeap in JavaScript visualizer

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

Does anyone know of a better equation that can change the column sizes evenly by row? As of now my 1st row will have one column of 100%, the 2nd row has 2 columns each measuring 50%, and the third row can potentially have 4 columns up to 25% width. I achieve this by dividing the column width by 2. I am visualizing a binary max heap.

Also, this is a problem because whenever I add a new node to the row, it will always start at 100% but does shrink accordingly. However, I want to make sure when a new node is added the respective column width is considered immediately. I am unsure how I can make this happen either in the CSS or JS.

```js
class MaxHeap {
    constructor() {
        this.data = [];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    getParentIndex(index) {
        if (index <= 0) {
            index = 0;
            return index;
        }
        return Math.floor((index - 1) / 2);
    }

    getLeftChildIndex(index) {
        return index * 2 + 1;
    }

    getRightChildIndex(index) {
        return index * 2 + 2;
    }

    add(value) {
        if (!this.data.includes(value)) {
            this.data[this.size] = value;
            this.size++;
            this.visualize();
            const newNodeIndex = this.size - 1;
            const newNode = document.querySelectorAll('.node')[newNodeIndex];
            newNode.classList.add('node-added');
            this.heapifyUp();
        }

    }

    extractMax() {
        if (this.size === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        // Highlight the last (bottom) node as red
        const lastNodeIndex = this.size - 1;
        const lastNode = document.querySelectorAll('.node')[lastNodeIndex];
        this.swap(0, lastNodeIndex);
        const maxNode = document.querySelectorAll('.node')[0];
        maxNode.classList.add('node-max');
        const max = this.data.pop();
        lastNode.remove();
        this.size--;
        setTimeout(() => {
            lastNode.classList.remove('node-extracting');
            maxNode.classList.remove('node-max');
        }, 1000);
        this.heapifyDown(0);
        return max;
    }

    swap(index1, index2) {
        const node1 = document.querySelectorAll('.node')[index1];
        const node2 = document.querySelectorAll('.node')[index2];
        node1.classList.add('node-swapping');
        node2.classList.add('node-swapping');
        const temp = this.data[index1];
        this.data[index1] = this.data[index2];
        this.data[index2] = temp;
        node1.textContent = this.data[index1];
        node2.textContent = this.data[index2];
        setTimeout(() => {
            node1.classList.remove('node-swapping');
            node2.classList.remove('node-swapping');
        }, 1000);
    }

    heapifyUp() {
        let currentIndex = this.size - 1;
        while (this.data[this.getParentIndex(currentIndex)] < this.data[currentIndex]) {
            const parentIndex = this.getParentIndex(currentIndex);
            this.swap(parentIndex, currentIndex);
            currentIndex = parentIndex;
        }
    }

    heapifyDown(currentIndex) {
        while (this.getLeftChildIndex(currentIndex) < this.size) {
            let biggestChildIndex = this.getLeftChildIndex(currentIndex);
            if (this.getRightChildIndex(currentIndex) < this.size &&
                this.data[this.getRightChildIndex(currentIndex)] > this.data[biggestChildIndex]) {
                biggestChildIndex = this.getRightChildIndex(currentIndex);
            }
            if (this.data[currentIndex] < this.data[biggestChildIndex]) {
                this.swap(currentIndex, biggestChildIndex);
                currentIndex = biggestChildIndex;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    // buildMaxHeap() {
    //     const lastNonLeafIndex = Math.floor(this.size / 2) - 1;
    //     for (let i = lastNonLeafIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
    //         this.heapifyDown(i);
    //     }
    // }

    toString() {
        let result = '[';
        for (let index = 0; index < this.size; index++) {
            result += this.data[index];
            if (index < this.size - 1) {
                result += ', ';
            }
        }
        result += ']';
        return result;
    }

    visualize() {
        const container = document.getElementById('maxHeapContainer');
        container.innerHTML = '';
        let level = 0;
        let nodesInLevel = 1;
        let nodesDisplayed = 0;
        let columnWidth = 100;
        while (nodesDisplayed < this.size) {
            const row = document.createElement('div');
            row.classList.add('level');
            container.appendChild(row);
            const elementsInRow = Math.min(nodesInLevel, this.size - nodesDisplayed);
            // console.log("Level " + level + " contains " + elementsInRow + " node(s)");
            const gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${elementsInRow}, minmax(${columnWidth}%, 1fr))`;
            row.style.gridTemplateColumns = gridTemplateColumns;
            for (let i = 0; i < elementsInRow; i++) {
                const node = document.createElement('div');
                node.classList.add('node');
                node.textContent = this.data[nodesDisplayed];
                row.appendChild(node);
                nodesDisplayed++;
            }
            level++;
            nodesInLevel = Math.pow(2, level);
            columnWidth /= 2;
        }
    }

}

const heap = new MaxHeap();
const addBtn = document.querySelector('button.submit-value');
const extractBtn = document.querySelector('button.extract-value');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('input.node-value').value);
    heap.add(inputValue);
});

extractBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    heap.extractMax();
})
```

```css
/* Keyframe swapping scale animation */
@keyframes swap {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

/* Animation for swapping nodes */
.node-swapping {
    animation: swap 1s;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: system-ui;
}

:root {
    --node-color: whitesmoke;
    --swap-color: #F9DA8B;
    --max-color: #E66A6A;
    --lastnode-color: #FAB8D9;
    --node-txt-color: #333;
    --nav-txt-color: whitesmoke;
    --nav-bg-color: #35469C;
    --main-bg-color: #E0E8F9;
    --primary-border-color: #D9E2EC;
    --input-bg-color: #D9E2EC;
    --primary-padding: 0.7rem;
}

/***** Nav Styling *******************************/
nav.navigation-bar {
    background-color: var(--nav-bg-color);
    padding: var(--primary-padding);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav.navigation-bar h1 {
    color: var(--nav-txt-color);
}

section.input-section {
    background-color: var(--nav-txt-color);
    padding: var(--primary-padding);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(80px, 1fr));
    gap: 0.2rem;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color: var(--input-bg-color);
    padding: 0.4rem;
    border: none;
}

button {
    padding: 0.3rem 1.1rem 0.3rem 1.1rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Main Section Styling ******************************/
main {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#maxHeapContainer {
    display: grid;
}

/* Styles for nodes */
.node {
    border: 4px solid var(--primary-border-color);
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    background-color: var(--node-color);
    padding: 0.4rem 1rem 0.4rem 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--node-txt-color);
    transition: background-color 1s;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Style for nodes being swapped and triggered by JavaScript*/
.node-swapping {
    background-color: var(--swap-color);
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

.node-max {
    background-color: var(--max-color);
}

.node-last {
    background-color: var(--lastnode-color);
}

.level {
    display: grid;
    gap: 0.3rem;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    nav.navigation-bar {
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 20vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navigation-bar">
        <h1>Max Heap Visualizer</h1>
        <section class="input-section">
            <input type="text" class="node-value" placeholder="Value">
            <button class="submit-value">Add</button>
            <button class="extract-value">ExtractMax</button>
            <!-- <button class="clear-value">Clear Heap</button> -->
        </section>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <div id="maxHeapContainer"></div>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js" async></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems that your elements offset because of the margins. In theory, if you set all margins between sibling elements to 0, everything should work perfectly. If you do need the margins, you'll have to somehow subtract them from the elements' width.